# Android center Bitmap in ImageView matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, imageview

I am working on an app where user can move his image within the screen, and then save it.
The problem is positioning Bitmap in ImageView on start of the activity.
Here is the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_content_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/top_image"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:scaleType="matrix"
           android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
           android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I am moving the ImageView (well, not ImageView, but its matrix) with *onTouch*, and it works well.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                start.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == DRAG)
                {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                }
                break;
        }
        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
```

**The problem** is the position of Bitmap on the start of Activity. It is aligned on *Top|Left* instead of *Center*. Like this:
[image]

Can anyone please  help me center it on start in ImageView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to align bitmap to center then you ImageView layout should be:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"/>
```

EDIT:

In case if you need scaleType "matrix" then use next solution:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    />
```

And then in code change offset of image:

```
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.top_image);

    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            Rect rectDrawable = drawable.getBounds();
            float leftOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredWidth() - rectDrawable.width()) / 2f;
            float topOffset = (imageView.getMeasuredHeight() - rectDrawable.height()) / 2f;

            Matrix matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
            matrix.postTranslate(leftOffset, topOffset);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need it to be android:scaleType="matrix" because I am moving it onTouch.

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But I need it to work on API level 10, and removeOnGlobalLayoutListener works on API level 16.

Comment: @filipst than use if statement, if Api Level less than 16 call imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

Comment: @filipst It works for me on My Galaxy Ace (Android 2.3.7). You do the same for image moving - view.setImageMatrix(matrix). Try to compile simple project without any additional implementation, maybe problem in another place.

Comment: I am using Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and it is working, but on Samsung tab GT-P5110 nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88453/discussion-between-alexandr-and-filipst).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    />
```